# Android Nexus One - trackball light

Tags: android

How can I control the trackball light in a nexus one ? I found something with NotificationManager but the samples do not work for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot yet.  Perhaps in a future update (the hardware is capable of it, my roommate has a custom ROM on his Nexus and the trackball is colorful. It's the software that blocks it).

Comment: That may be true for controlling colors, but you can definitely use the `NotificationManager` to toggle the white light. Leastways, it works for some apps I have installed (e.g., Remember The Milk).

Comment: In NotificationManager i can use the FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS flag which is supose to turn on the LED.
The thing is Nexus one has 2 LED ( one in the trackball and a small one at top right). Which one is "THE" led ?:D

Comment: There's no light at the top.  Are you talking about the light sensor?

Comment: When the phone is connected to USB in the top right corner there is a small red led.( on nexus one at least)

Comment: I don't believe the charging LED is an android controlled one, as it's most likely built in straight to the hardware. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to see the charging light when the phone was off.